# Parse XML File for an element's value by using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, powershell, cmd, batch-processing, getelementsbytagname

I have an XML file in which I can get an element's value via the following PowerShell command.

```
PS C:\> $xmlDoc = Get-Content [fullPathToXmlFile]
ps C:\> $xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("MyElement")
```

Since there is only 1  in the specified Xml document, I get this result:

[Value contained within the  tag.]

My problem is not knowing how to use a similar script within a batch file to store this value into a variable.

My goal is to extract a single value from a unique element within an Xml document via a batch file so that this variable can be used inside the same batch file.

Example:

set MyVar = someMethodToExtractMyElementsValue //This method will result in an integer

I will then use %MyVar% as part of a full path later in the batch file.

Comment: So your goal is to query XML in a batch (.cmd/.bat) file?

Comment: If you can't use powershell your best bet is a vbscript from the batch file or download a third party xml parser exe

Answer (score 0):

From the batch script call your snippet it like this:

```
set d = powershell -noprofile "& { $xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("MyElement") }"
```

if the code is more complex place it in a .ps1 file and execute a script instead of an scriptblock

Hope this helps

Comment: This sets d to the string literal. What am I missing?